# SharePoint 2013 - Alternative ways to make Web Parts

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

If I don't have SharePoint Designer 2013 or Visual Studio, are there are web applications I can simply install and run and experiment with,  to make custom parts for SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. You can also create a part of SharePoint 2013 or other version by html, xml and javascript. In this way you can use javascript object model (JSOM).

Follow the following links to get knowledge about that:

[http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20764.sharepoint-2013-build-a-webpart-using-html-javascript-and-the-xml-viewer-web-part.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163201(v=office.15))

And here are the link to reference to use JOSM:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163201(v=office.15)

Hope this help.